# Create new window vertical with shortcuts in vim?

Tags: vim

How can I create new window with new buffer in `vim`, vertical with shortcuts?
(Similar to Ctrl-w n, but vertically.)

Comment: Inverse of the action?  Or reverse of the window split whilst keeping the buffer?  Or split in the opposite direction?  Or split in the perpendicular direction?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The <kbd>Ctrl+W</kbd><kbd>n</kbd> shortcut is the same as the `new`command.  There is also a `vnew` command that works exactly as `new`, but splits vertically.  To use it, type <kbd>Esc</kbd>`:vnew`<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

You could also remap e.g. <kbd>Ctrl+W</kbd><kbd>v</kbd> from doing the equivalent of `vsplit` (the default) to `vnew` using something like

```
noremap <C-w>v <esc>:vnew<cr>
```

in your `~/.vimrc` file.

---

Note: When the below answer was written, the question asked for the "contrary" action to <kbd>Ctrl+W</kbd><kbd>n</kbd>. I interpreted this as "the opposite of splitting and creating a new window, i.e. closing a split window".

The `q` command closes the current buffer (this would be entered as <kbd>Esc</kbd>`:q`<kbd>Enter</kbd>).  If that is done in one of the buffers that you get from splitting, you will get back to an editor window containing only a single buffer, reversing the effect of <kbd>Ctrl+W</kbd><kbd>n</kbd>.

You may also use <kbd>Ctrl+W</kbd><kbd>q</kbd> for doing this.

Comment: Thanks and sorry for my english!!

Comment: But you have mapped "ctrl-w v" which is used to divide the screen vertically but WITHOUT new buffer ... Of DEFAULT, there is no shortcut for ":vnew"?

Comment: For config file using lua: `vim.keymap.set('n', '<C-w>v', '<esc>:vnew<cr>', { noremap = true})`

Comment: @FanchenBao I suppose that would be for NeoVim, not Vim, right?

Comment: Yes, for NeoVim. I should've specified it in the comment.